# SCP doesn't work when using a command to get the file name

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, zsh

I am trying to automate an import backup script.

For that, I am using this command to get the last backup file name:

```
BACKUP_NAME=$(ssh user@XX.XX.XX.XX-t "ls -w1 /mnt/prod_backup" | tail -1)
```

And then I use

```
scp -3 user@$YY.YY.YY.YY:/mnt/prod_backup/$BACKUP_NAME /home/coldstorage_import/
```

to try download the file so I can use it to restore the local database.

But I get this error:

```
: No such file or directoryackup/backup_prod_2021-11-29-03-00-01.sql
```

The patch error looks wrong.

When, I try to download the file by copy/pasting the file name manually the command works.

My guess is that there is a special/hidden char somewhere perhaps but I can't figure it out..

Edit:

When running this command to try see the hidden characters

```
echo $BACKUP_NAME | cat -v
```

I get

```
bizstore_backup_prod_2021-11-16-03-00-01.sql^M
```

I am not sure if `^M` is normal or not.

Comment: Looks like there was a CR character in the output of `ssh`. Is the remote or local machine running some Microsoft OS?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas

Both servers are running the same version of Ubuntu.

But I am using Git bash from windows to connect to one of them.

I edited my answer, to show the result of a command which should show the hidden char.

Comment: @Archemar 

It is a typo, I forget to update one of the command when trying to simplify the path. I edited my question, sorry for that.

Comment: Related: [Why is this binary file transferred over "ssh -t" being changed?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/151916)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an optimisation/potential bug-fix: You should use `ls -rt /mnt/prod_backup/*.sql` so that the files are sorted by reverse time and only those ending in .sql are listed.   Note: if you have filenames with newlines in them, you'll have to do something like (requires GNU utils): `find /mnt/prod_backup/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.sql' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -zrn | head -zn1 | cut -zf2-`.   Also, double-quote your variables when you use them - it only takes one filename with an unexpected space (or `;` or `&` or whatever) to break your script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `-t` from your `ssh` command and the `^M` won't appear in the filename:

```
BACKUP_NAME="$(ssh user@XX.XX.XX.XX "ls -w1 /mnt/prod_backup" | tail -1)"
```

Comment: Once you remove the `-t` you also don't need `-w1` on `ls` because with stdout to a pipe (not a pty) it automatically does one-entry-per-line.